# Why does typescript complain when I import a component, but not when the component is defined in the same file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an issue where I get two different results from Typescript's type check when I import a component from another file vs define the component in the same file where it's used.

I made a sandbox to describe question in more detail: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-error-1l44t?file=/src/App.tsx

If you look at `Example` function, I'm passing in an additional parameter `z`, which shouldn't be valid, therefore I'm getting an error (as expected).

However if you enable L15-L22 where `ExampleComponent` is defined in the same file, then disable or remove the `ExampleComponent` import from `'./component'` on L2, suddenly Typescript stops complaining.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

If there's any extra information I can give, please let me know.

Comment: Error will disappear if you explicitly tell to TypeScript that `Example` is a function component by writing `type Component<T> = React.FunctionComponent< ...`.

Comment: @AjeetShah do you know why I get a different result when I define the component inside the file? I'm just very curious.

Comment: Looks like a bug in TypeScript

Comment: Anyway you should prefer declaring a normal function `function ExampleComponent(props: { foo: string })` as opposed to what you are doing

Comment: @Devin It works without error when you define the component inside the file (*not importing from another file*) because TS interprets it as `FunctionComponent` but not when you import it. So, either you can explicitly tell by using `React.FunctionComponent` or just declare a function like @ torvin [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67865309/why-does-typescript-complain-when-i-import-a-component-but-not-when-the-compone?noredirect=1#comment119954523_67865309).

Comment: @AjeetShah got it, very interesting. Thanks both.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your are refining a type in one scope, but if you export that value you don't also get those refinements.

In other words, when you create the value in the same file, Typescript can infer a more specific subtype. But when it's in another file it just imports whatever the most broad type that it could possibly be.

Here's a simpler example:

```
// test.ts
export const test: string | number = 'a string';
test.toUpperCase(); // works
```

This works because typescript observed that `test` is a string because of the assignment of a string literal. There is no way that, after executing the code of that file, `test` could be a number.

However, `test` is still typed as `string | number`. It's just that *in this scope* typescript can apply a refinement to a more narrow type.

Now let's import `test` into another file:

```
// other.ts
import { test } from './test'
test.toUpperCase() // Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type 'string | number'.
```

Refinements only get applied in the scope where they were refined. That means that you get the more broad type when you export that value.

---

Another example:

```
// test.ts
export const test = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'abc' : 123 // string | number
if (typeof test === 'string') throw Error('string not allowed!')
const addition = test + 10 // works fine

// other.ts
import { test } from './test'
const addition = test + 10 // Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'string | number' and 'number'.(2365)
```

In this case the program should throw an exception if a string is assigned. In the `test.ts` file, typescript knows that and therefore knows that `test` must be a number if that third line is executing.

However, the exported type is still `string | number` because that's what *you* said it was.

---

In your code, `React.ComponentType<P>` is actually an alias for:

```
React.ComponentClass<P, any> | React.FunctionComponent<P>
```

Typescript notices that you are assigning a function, and not a class, and refines that type to `React.FunctionComponent<P>`. But when you import from another file it could be either, so typescript is more paranoid, and you get the type error.

And, lastly, for a reason I haven't yet figured out, your code works with a function component, but not with a class component. But this should at least make it clear why there's a difference at all.